# Not able to import marked js from @types.marked in react app

Tags: reactjs

I have installed marked js in react app using `npm install --save @types/marked`.
Below is the react component:

```
import { marked } from "marked";
// import { marked } from "../../node_modules/@types/marked/index";
// import { marked } from "../../node_modules/@types/marked/index.mjs";
// import * as marked from "marked";

const MyPage : React.FC = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            { marked("Hello world from MyPage.") }
        </div>
    )
}

export default MyPage;
```

As you can see in below screenshot of tooltip in VS code, the intellisence knows where the actual function is.

[image: description]

But the app does not compile, I get the following errors (corresponding to different styles of imports for marked in comments):
`Module not found: Can't resolve 'marked' in 'D:\coding\myblog\blog-frontend\src\app-components'`
`Module not found: Can't resolve '../../node_modules/@types/marked/index.mjs' in 'D:\coding\myblog\blog-frontend\src\app-components'`

Basically, what ever string that I am providing after `from` in import statement, react tries to find it in `~/src/app-components`. But all other imports are working fine (like my servies, models etc).

Comment: make sure you also  to install `marked`, the library itself
`npm install marked --save`

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a bit late, but I had the same issue and could resolve it with:

```
npm install --save marked
```

In your package.json file you can look up dependencies if it's correct installed.

I used `npm install -g marked` at first and that wasn't really working despite getting the feedback that it was installed.